# Zoho Creator with Bootstrap, jQuery, or other custom HTML

Tags: zoho

Does Zoho Creator have a built-in way of letting me serve views to users that are styled with Bootstrap or use jQuery controls or otherwise are just HTML albeit using ZC as the backend?

If not, is there a simple way of serving a custom frontend like this on a separate host but connecting it up to use ZC as the backend?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an article about how to make calls to the Zoho Creator backend here:

http://www.lighthouselogic.com/cross-domain-ajax-requests-to-zoho-creator/

I have used this technique successfully to host a simple html and javascript frontend that talks directly to the Zoho Database.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other options:

1. Check if Zoho-Creator's own customization capability is enough to configure the desired style.  See the **'Customize look and feel of published and embedded Forms'** section of:
   https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/forms/embed-form-report-in-website.html
2. Using the Zoho-Creator API, query the Form. The API will return the data in JSON (or XML if requested).  Then build the styled webpage with Bootstrap and JQuery parsing the JSON as needed.  Here is the API reference:
   https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/v2/
3. Create Zoho-Creator Widgets.  Zoho-Creator Widgets are Javascript and can include Zoho's JS APIs as well as additional Javascript libraries such as Bootstrap and jQuery.  Here is the link to their main documentation.
   https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/app-settings/widgets/understand-widgets.html.
   It is also helpful to search out other examples of Zoho Widgets to fill in some of the details of how to implement.  **Be aware, The widgets with Zoho's JS APIs will not work on the Zoho published pages.**